# Adding namespace functions in header files

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm trying to use header files to transfer functions in a namespace on a separate file to another file, and it's returning the error

> "Add" is not a member of "simple".

I simply want to know if it's possible to use forward function declarations rather than declaring the function every time in the header, which supposedly would keep copying the code for every .cpp that includes it.
Here's the basic outline for 1.cpp, 2.cpp and 3.h.

**1.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
// Check this header file for function declarations.
#include "3.h"

int main()
{
    //Example of a single namespace.
    std::cout << simple::add(3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

**2.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
namespace simple {
    int simple::add(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

**3.h**

```
#ifndef NAMESPACES
#define NAMESPACES
namespace simple {
    int simple::add(int, int);
}
#endif
```

Much appreciation to anyone who answers, and apologies if this has been asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue, for any future viewers of this thread.
You don't use the prepending "simple::" on header declarations, or in the function itself, as I did.

Corrected code:

**3.h**

```
#ifndef NAMESPACES
#define NAMESPACES
//Header guards are important!
namespace simple {
    int add(int, int);
}
#endif
```

**2.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "3.h"
int simple::add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

No changes are required to 1.cpp.

Comment: Why did you add extern to 2.cpp?

Comment: Good question, it's not needed. Functions are already defaultly externally linked. I'll remove it now.

Comment: This is all explained reasonably well in this [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace). Oh, and you can also _define_ the function as `simple::add` without using the namespace wrapper.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll be sure to use that in future. The technique you mentioned didn't work the way I tried it though, as it mentioned that the "simple" must be a namespace or class name. @Useless

Comment: Simple typographical error, I do not see a need for an answer.

Comment: Other people may make the same error, so this may be useful for people in future, even if it wasn't for you. Don't discourage questions for the sake of discouraging questions. @SergeyA

Comment: @LarryTang Other people might make the error of missing semicolon, yet, one shouldn't write Q/A for any possible place, where one might miss a semicolon.

Comment: Oh, you didn't include `3.h` in  `2.cpp`. The compiler won't know `simple` is a namespace if it never saw the declaration.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll finish the edit now.